# How to Increase RAM Limit of Windows Server 2008 Standard

Tags: windows, memory

I would like to be able to install 48GB of RAM in my server, but it seems Windows Server 2008 Standard limits me to 32GB.

How do I install more RAM in my server?

Comment: Hee hee.  (http://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/2430071415 for reference)

Comment: Arbitrary hardware limits? Every time I find myself thinking 'maybe Microsoft aren't such a big bunch of a holes' something like this crops up and I'm reminded why Linux is superior. @Microsoft: do yourself a favour and stop being a holes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will have to upgrade to an Enterprise or Datacenter version of Windows.

Additionally, if you want to use more than 2 GB of memory for any one process, you'll have to upgrade to the 64 bit version.

[Available memory table from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

To go beyond 32 Gigs you'll need to upgrade Windows 2008 Enterprise Edition.